# show multiple text when select option is select

Tags: javascript

I have multiple div, I want to display 2 hidden text when I select the value of 1, when I choose value of 2 it will display 4 hidden text etc.

```js
function showDiv(divId, element) {
  document.getElementById('depositProductType').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var style = this.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('allowJoint').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('allowTransfer').style.display = style;
    var style = this.value == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('allowJoint').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('allowTransfer').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('allowDisabling').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('createOne').style.display = style;

    var style = this.value == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('allowTransfer').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('createOne').style.display = style;

  });
}
```

```html
<select id="depositProductType" name="prod_type" onchange="showDiv('allowJoint','allowTransfer','allowDisabling','createOne', this)">
  <option class="blank" value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Fixed Deposit</option>
  <option value="2">Savings Deposit</option>
  <option value="3">Scheduled Deposit</option>
</select>

<!-- this is the multiple div I want to display from my html -->
<div id="allowJoint"> ------- </div>
<div id="allowTransfer"> ------ </div>
<div id="allowDisabling"> ------- </div>
<div id="createOne"> ---------- </div>
```

Comment: you can use jquery for that and can you explain more about your issue

Comment: @Chris kindly provide more details about your issue, from your code its unclear how one can help you.

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well, please?

Comment: I have multiple div, I want to display 2 hidden text when I select the value of 1, when I choose value of 2 it will display 4 hidden text etc.

Comment: My html is too long

Comment: Can you reduce your HTML to just the relevant parts? Without HTML, we can't help you, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change you select to only pass the element

```
<select id="depositProductType" name="prod_type" onchange="showDiv(this)">
```

Then you showDiv can no need to listen to event since it is trigger by the onChange event already. Just call your function.

```
function showDiv(ele) {
    var allowJoint = document.getElementById('allowJoint');
    var allowTransfer = document.getElementById('allowTransfer');
    var allowDisabling = document.getElementById('allowDisabling');
    var createOne = document.getElementById('createOne');
    if(ele.value == 1) {
        allowJoint.style.display = 'block';
        allowTransfer.style.display = 'block';
        allowDisabling.style.display = 'none';
        createOne.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(ele.value == 2) {
        allowJoint.style.display = 'block';
        allowTransfer.style.display = 'block';
        allowDisabling.style.display = 'block';
        createOne.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if(ele.value == 3) {
        allowTransfer.style.display = 'block';
        createOne.style.display = 'block';
        allowJoint.style.display = 'none';
        allowDisabling.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a bug. when the 4 hidden text showed, the others can't hide when i select the first value
sorry for my english

Comment: See my update JS code. I forgot to add the hide code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showDiv(element) {
  var old_element = document.getElementById("depositProductType");
  var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);
  document.getElementById('depositProductType').addEventListener('change', function() {
console.log(this.value)
    document.getElementById('allowJoint').style.display = (this.value == 1 || this.value == 2) ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('allowTransfer').style.display = (this.value == 1 || this.value == 2) ? 'block' : 'none';

    document.getElementById('allowDisabling').style.display = (this.value == 3 || this.value == 2) ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('createOne').style.display = (this.value == 3 || this.value == 2) ? 'block' : 'none';

  });
}
```

```html
<select id="depositProductType" name="prod_type" onchange="showDiv(this)">
  <option class="blank" value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Fixed Deposit</option>
  <option value="2">Savings Deposit</option>
  <option value="3">Scheduled Deposit</option>
</select>

<!-- this is the multiple div I want to display from my html -->
<div id="allowJoint" style="display: none"> allowJoint </div>
<div id="allowTransfer" style="display: none"> allowTransfer </div>
<div id="allowDisabling" style="display: none"> allowDisabling </div>
<div id="createOne" style="display: none"> createOne </div>
```

Comment: the output still the same